# How to add event to exit a window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I know that it is possible to close an application by calling the `exit(0)` function. And that by using it, all heap-allocated memory prior to the call is cleared. So you do not have to worry about it.

But to debug your program and investigate better if there is a memory leak, it is not practical to close the program without first releasing all memory.

So I wanted to schedule the closure by adding the same message that the system sends by pressing the X button on a window (`WM_CLOSE`).

With that message(or event), the program can execute the code that will close the application.

*So the question is if there is any function, or something from the winapi that adds that message to the current process?*

Comment: The message loop receives the `WM_CLOSE` message.

Comment: Pretty much wrong, all around. The analysis is, how some developer might think things are. This is not the case. For one, not every window provides the ability to close it through a button. Those that do, can do it in a number of different ways. The standard Windows way is to have a system menu entry, that eventually causes the close button to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window's window procedure. The default implementation (`DefWindowProc`) responds by calling `DestroyWindow` on the window handle.

Comment: Regardless of the edits you keep pushing, you have a history of asking about [XY Problems](http://xyproblem.info). Pretty sure, this is the case here, too. So what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable, I simply want to schedule the closing of an application. I can not call `exit(0)` inside a function that are not able to free some of the heap datas created before. I'll try the `DestroyWindow ` you mentioned ;)

Comment: Not freeing heap-allocated memory prior to calling `exit(0)` doesn't change one thing. You are tearing down a process. Why clean up prior to tearing down the house? And how do you propose to get into the target process, and *"schedule the closing of an application"* (whatever that is supposed to mean).

Comment: @IInspectable unfortunately, generations of bad textbooks and worse profs have indoctrinated developers into believing that neglecting to explicitly free heap memory before terminating a process is the fifth horse of the apocalypse and an extinction level event.   It's a faith-based thing that cannot be argued with:(

Comment: I'm unable to ask more questions. stackoverflow does not accept any more questions from me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WINAPI `SendMessage` with `WM_CLOSE` for the `Msg` parameter.

Here more about this function: [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

if you Can Replace `WM_CLOSE` With `SIGINT` You Can Do a Simple Signal On `SIGINT` That Calls Your own Function (Don't Know That You Can Use It On `WM_CLOSE` But Tested with `SIGINT` On Windows)

here's Example Of Signal In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx)

here's how to emit `SIGINT` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482702/using-sigint)

Comment: Hard to know what this answer is about. What's with all. The off-site links?

Comment: From the MSDN page you linked: "SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application."